# put ps plus on wrong acount

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus

I accidentally put a 12-month ps plus subscription on my own account instead of the family account on my ps4. Will the family account account still be able to access the games it downloaded before its ps plus expired?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. **But only until the family account PS+ expires**. Once expired, **everyone** loses access to them. Even though you now have a PS+ on your personal account, that account did not purchase (or get as a freebie) the games in question*.

If you download any freebies while having the PS+ subscription, everyone will lose access to them when your 12-months are up unless you keep that subscription going.

So your options are:

- Buy another 12-month subscription and put it on the family account to keep access to all the old games
- Forever lose access to all the old games and only have PS+ on your account going forward
- Alternate which account has PS+ and which games are accessible

.* In the highly unlike event that you *PAID* for the game on your own account even though the family account had it for free, then yes, everyone will still have access to the game.